# PHP. Оставить один элемент массива, если он повторяется

Tags: php

Есть массив:

```
$array = array(90,25,25,25,25);
```

Дальше вывожу все элементы по-очереди:

```
foreach ($array as $value)
{
    echo '<li>'.$value.'</li>';
}
```

Получаю на выходе:

```
<li>90</li>
<li>25</li>
<li>25</li>
<li>25</li>
<li>25</li>
```

Хочу получить:

```
<li>90</li>
<li>0</li>
<li>0</li>
<li>0</li>
<li>25</li>
```

Помогите советом.
Язык программирования php.

В идеале мне нужно превращать в 0 все элементы массива, которые повторяются.

Ломаю голову весь вечер. Помогите, кто понимает как это сделать.

Comment: Если не обязательно оставлять нули, то можно использовать array_unique().

Comment: С сожалению не подойдет без нулей...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Довольно интересная задачка, хоть и выглядит простой.

Чтобы оптимизировать количество итераций, нужно создать второй, ассоциативный, массив со всеми имеющимися в исходном массиве значениями и для каждого значения хранить его смещение в исходном массиве. При сканировании исходного массива, если какое-то значение найдено в ассоциативном массиве, то зануляем его в исходном массиве по смещению из ассоциативного массива, а затем прописываем новое смещение.

Код вот такой:

```
$array = array(90,25,30,25,90);
$values = array();

//Ищем дубликаты
for ($x = 0; $x < count($array); $x++) {
    $curr = $array[$x];
    //Если текущее значение в исходном массиве уже существует как
    //ключ в ассоциативном массиве значений
    if (array_key_exists($curr,$values)) {
        //То берем предыдущее смещение текущего значения в исходном массиве
        $index = $values[$curr];
        //И обнуляем его в исходном массиве по данному смещению
        $array[$index] = 0;
    }
    //Сохраняем смещение текущего значения в массив значений
    $values[$curr] = $x;
} 

foreach ($array as $value)
{
    echo '<li>'.$value.'</li>';
}
```

Протестировано на [phptester](http://phptester.net/)

### P.S.

Кстати, если бы мы оставляли первый из найденных дубликатов, а не последний, то можно было бы избежать второго перебора исходного массива. Код бы тоже упростился...